# where to place *further* , *considering further*

Tags: word-order

As the closing sentence of a cover letter for an application I would like to write the sentence

> I would appreciate your **further considering my application** and remain...

but is this correct, or should I rather place the word *further* differently?
The options are

1. I would appreciate your **considering my application further** and remain...
2. I would appreciate your **considering further my application** and remain...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We don't need 'further.'

Comment: 'remain...' what? Even knowing the whole sentence I would advise against this particular example.    _'I appreciate your consideration of my application and please do not hesitate to contact me if you require any further information.'_  This is how I would end the cover letter.  HTH

Comment: In fact, this is a letter written for an ongoing application process and I will hand in this letter after the first interview. That is why I am writing *further*. I am just unsure about the correct placement of the word. The ...-part is just a "Yours faithfully".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said "ongoing", as an adjective, further could be used in the sense **'additional.'**

> The meeting ended without any plans for **further** discussions.

```
       I would appreciate your considering my application further....
```

In the same vein, you could use further in your sentence, however, in my opinion a better construction will be:

> I would appreciate your **further** consideration of my application 
>   or
>
> As @Joe states, 'I appreciate your consideration of my application
>   [Further discussion](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/fartherterm.htm)

Comment: Thank you, I think you understood what I meant ;) My thought was that they already considered my application by inviting me to an interview. And so I would be appreciating their further consideration of my application. I have never before sent them a letter, but will have met them by the time I hand it to them... The question is much more of a grammatical nature, not so much of *why* I want to say *further*.

Answer (score 0):

> I would appreciate your further consideration of my application...

However, it still doesn't feel quite right to me but it's hard to be exact without knowing the process. So the following might be helpful (or might not!):

> Thank you for my recent interview. I enclose my application for your further consideration as agreed.